# LARAVEL 7 One to One Relationship Dropdown list only display items with no relationship

Tags: php, laravel-7, one-to-one

I'm using Laravel 7 and creating a dropdown list where the book should only display items that do not relate to the student because I'm creating a one on one relationship. How am I going to do that?

Create View

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="book">Book <span class="required">*</span></label>

    
        <select class="form-select" style="color: #41A7A5" aria-label="Default select example" name="book">
        <option value="">Select Book</option>
           @foreach ($books as $book)
           @if($book->students->book_id == $book->id)
           <option name="book" value="{{$book->id}}">{{$book->name}}</option>  
           
           @endif
           @endforeach
        </select>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**Student Controller - Create**

```
 public function create(){
  $students = Student::query()->with('books')->latest();
     $books = Book::all();
    return view('students.create',compact('students','books'));
 }
```

**Book Model**

```
class Book extends Model{


protected $fillable = [
    'name','description' 
 ];
 
 public function students(): HasOne
 {
     return $this->hasOne(Student::class, 'book_id', 'id');
 }}
```

**Student Model**

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'book_id','name' 
 ];

 public function books(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class, 'book_id');
}}
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are trying to show only the books that are linked to a students ?

Comment: @Nicolas, I would like to show in the dropdown the list of books who are not yet linked to a student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `all()` function, on your `Book` model, you could filter out the books that have a related student using the [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) function.

This function take a relation as a parameter and returns all the models that does not have any related model for that relation.

Please note that since we've added a condition to the query, we need to use `get()` rather than `all()`.

```php
 public function create(){
    $students = Student::query()->with('books')->latest();
    
    // retrieve all the book without a student related to it
    $books = Book::doesntHave('students')->get();

    return view('students.create',compact('students','books'));
 }
```

As a side note, since you re creating a 0,1 <-> 0,1 relation between the `Student` and the `Book` model, you might want to rename the respective relations for `book` and `student`. Otherwise, it might get confusing when comming back to the code later.